# How to Fix Youtube Data API v3 Required Parameter: part in Axios request and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run some queries with the Youtube Data API v3 which should return some videos from the Youtube API but I get an error of "Required parameter: part"

I have tried making the same request (GET) on Postman with same key value pairs and it works just fine in Postman but not inside of my React and Axios app where it spews this error:

```
{error: {errors: [,…], code: 400, message: "Required parameter: part"}}
error: {errors: [,…], code: 400, message: "Required parameter: part"}
code: 400
errors: [,…]
0: {domain: "global", reason: "required", message: "Required parameter: part", locationType: "parameter",…}
domain: "global"
location: "part"
locationType: "parameter"
message: "Required parameter: part"
reason: "required"
message: "Required parameter: part"
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

const KEY = 'AIzaSyAL9jCDWvRD2G5nUgBrLEgEhZTQsRvzt80';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
  params: {
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 5,
    key: KEY
  }
});
```

and my App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import youtube from '../components/apis/youtube';

class App extends React.Component {

  onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    youtube.get('/search', {
      params: {
        q: term
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting your `params` in your `App` component.

See [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hoover-dbebd), and code below.

You could do something like the following:

```
import axios from "axios";
const KEY = "AIzaSyAL9jCDWvRD2G5nUgBrLEgEhZTQsRvzt80";

export const baseParams = {
  part: "snippet",
  maxResults: 5,
  key: KEY
};

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3"
});
```

And then  your react component

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import youtube, { baseParams } from '../components/apis/youtube';

class App extends React.Component {

  onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    youtube.get('/search', {
      params: {
        ...baseParams,
        q: term
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Paul. I noticed you didn't use the Spread operator in the App Component but you did in the codesandox so I just adjusted my code

Comment: `

import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
// import youtube from '../components/apis/youtube';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=${term}`, {
      params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 5,
        key: 'AIzaSyAL9jCDWvRD2G5nUgBrLEgEhZTQsRvzt80'
      }
    });
  }

`

Also solves the problem but then you'd be doing everything inside of the App component

Comment: yeah, you could do it all in the `App` component, but thought maybe you wanted to reuse this in other parts of your app

Comment: This helped me pick up a few things I didn't know yet, very helpful.  Instructor did not refactor this way, there must be a lot of people following along who reached an abrupt end, unless they were lucky enough to find your solution.  Question:  Why the ... before baseParams variable?

Comment: @AveryFreeman the `...` is called a spread operator, and basically makes a copy of the object referenced. It would be the same as doing `params: { part: "snippet  maxResults: 5, key: 1, q: term }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald thank you, I learned about these in a later lesson, but description not as succinct as yours.  I really appreciate it.