# React / Axios - "code": 400, "message": "Required parameter: part"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request to my youtube api, and I get this back, even though I have included "part" :

```
"code": 400, "message": "Required parameter: part"
```

and from the network tab:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: part"
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong here ?

Here are my files :

youtube.js

```js
const KEY = "my api key";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: { 
      part: "snippet",
      maxResults: 5,
      key: KEY
  }
});
```

my app:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  onSearchSubmit = term => {
    const x = youtube.get("/search", {
      params: {
        q: term
      }
    });
    console.log(x);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ui container'>
        <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and finally my SearchBar.js :

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { term: "" };

  onInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  };

  onformSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.term);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ui segment search-bar'>
        <form onSubmit={this.onformSubmit} action='' className='ui form'>
          <div className='field'>
            <label htmlFor=''>Video Search</label>
            <input
              value={this.state.term}
              type='text'
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Been trying to figure it out without any luck. ( I know I'm not saving the fetch response, I just wanted to test the GET first before I do that. )

Axios - 0.18

Thanks !!!

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason : Overwriting of params

```
 const KEY = "my api key";
    export const baseParams = {
      part: "snippet",
      maxResults: 5,
      key: KEY
    };

    export default axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3"
    })



    import React from 'react';
    import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
    import youtube, { baseParams } from '../components/apis/youtube';

    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {};

      onSearchSubmit = term => {
        const x = youtube.get("/search", {
          params: {
          ...baseParams,
            q: term
          }
        });
        console.log(x);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className='ui container'>
            <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
          </div>
        );
```

Ignore the below as you have mistakenly added data initially.

Remove data inside param section in Youtube.js,It will work.

```
const KEY = "my api key";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {

      part: "snippet",
      maxResults: 5,
      key: KEY

  }

});
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, data isn't actually there. I was just trying stuff out being desperate, i have edited it. And it still doesn't work :(

Comment: you get the same error without the data key in you params object like Anilm suggested?

Comment: That is correct. That was the original way I tried it, and then I added data and forgot to remove it.

Comment: when you send the request for the search api, can you look in the network tab and paste what the url is? i copied your code exactly and it requested this url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&key=asdasd&q=sips` which is valid except for my fake key? response was `"reason": "keyInvalid",`

Comment: Also use async await while calling api

Comment: @sillenius https://blog.bitsrc.io/make-a-simple-react-app-with-using-youtube-api-68fa016e5a03
You can refer this link,This is the same app that you are trying I guess.

Comment: I'm using 0.18, I did initially use 0.19, but I did uninstall and install 0.18. Still the same problem :/

Comment: @TomFinney the url is : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?data=%7B%22part%22:%22snippet%22,%22maxResults%22:5,%22key%22:%22AIzaSyAtnhS2znHwoKJbbYEY242MbCwCynt0zZ4%22%7D&q=sajdi

Comment: @sillenius  See the first answer might be the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517062/how-to-fix-youtube-data-api-v3-required-parameter-part-in-axios-request-and-rea

Comment: That was it thank you !!!!

Can you post it as a normal answer instead of a comment so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Axios v0.20.0 release resolved this issue, which was released this past summer.

The problem was that there is a bug with v0.19.0 that fails to merge the parameters from the config instance. This will cause a 400 error failure with the message "Required Parameter: part". So you can deal with it a couple of ways.

1. `npm install axios@0.20.0`
2. Follow the answer given by @Anilm and remove params object to somewhere else like your `onSearchSubmit`.